# what are ember js static data best practices

Tags: json, ember.js

I have some static data which will never change, like the data behind menu items

```
{
  "menuItems": [{
    "name": "Shows",
    "route": "shows"
  }, {
    "name": "Podcasts",
    "route": "podcasts"
  }]
}
```

i created a json file in `/dist` folder and in the application route i'm creating a model from the file like

```
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return $.getJSON('/static/model.json')
  }
});
```

is there a better practice to initialize model with static data?

Comment: FYI- Whatever you put it into file `public` folder will automatically come in dist folder, you dont need to manually do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already was said in other answer, you are not supposed to edit files in `dist/` folder.

You can do the following:

1. Create a new folder under `app/`. Let's say `app/constants/`
2. In that folder create new file `menu.js`:

   ```
   export default {
     "menuItems": [{
       "name": "Shows",
       "route": "shows"
     }, {
       "name": "Podcasts",
       "route": "podcasts"
     }]
   };
   ```
3. In any other file import it as `import menu from 'project-name/constants/menu';`. And I don't think you need a model for this, you can just use what you export.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be editing the `dist/` folder - that's where Ember sticks compiled code.

If your static data is only used in a single place, it would be more direct to put it where it's used as a `const`. In this specific case, that's UI code, and probably belongs in the controller.

The model hook is best for loading data that potentially changes each time you hit that route - probably from a back end.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can install [`ember-cli-json-module`](https://github.com/IvyApp/ember-cli-json-module) and then, any JSON files in either app or tests will be converted to ES6 modules that you can import like so: 
   `import myFixture from 'my-app/tests/fixtures/my-fixture';`